# Screencast of my AR iOS App

Tags: ios, opengl-es, camera, avfoundation

I'm working on an app which combines the camera with some OpenGL. The usual "AR" thing. I know how to record the camera, I know how to record OpenGL, I've just failed with a thousand of different options :( over the last 4 days. After I'm wondering if this is *at all* doable / supported / feasable.

Answer (score 0):

Just use glReadPixels on your finished AR-ed rendering.